# Fullcalendar External Drop set id dropped item (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC solution. My issue is that when I drop an external item into calendar, I want to set the id taken from database where I have put the new record. So what I do is in the drop event of fullcalendar, pass the data of the record drag, then in the server side, with controller I insert the information in the DB and then I pass with a json to the success method the id to update the dropped item. I have sharch a lot. I found solutions that create a new event (and I would not do it), and other solutions that doesn't work. This is my code:

**JQUERY**

```
    drop: function (date, jsEvent) {

        var currentRow = $(this);

        var Customer = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
        var Sign = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
        var Qta = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();

        var rowdata = {
            'StartDate': date.format(),
            'Customer': Customer,
            'Sign': Sign,
            'Qta': Qta
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: rowdata,
            async: false,
            url: "/Home/SaveEventDrop",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                 NewID = response.id;
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });

        $(this).remove();
        // HERE IS WHAT I WANT TO DO
        this.id = NewID;


    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult SaveEventDrop(string StartDate, string Customer, string Sign, string Qta)
    {
        SchedulerCalendar record = new SchedulerCalendar();

        //Formating the data
        Customer = Customer.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "").Trim();
        Sign = Sign.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "").Trim();
        Qta = Qta.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "").Trim();
        float FloatQta = float.Parse(Qta, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);

        record.customer = Customer;
        record.sign = Sign;
        record.qta = FloatQta;

        record.startDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
        record.endDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);

        db.schedulerCalendars.Add(record);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return Json(record);
    }
```

So if someone can let me understand how to get the dropped element in drop function, and how to update id, I will give him a lot of thanks!!!

Thank you

Comment: this.id = NewID; gets set potentially before NewID is assigned. Have you checked the NewID being assigned in the success of the ajax call? does the ajax return the ID as expected?

Comment: I have debugged it and the ajax return correctly the ID, but I'm not able to put it on the element of the calendar.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the new dropped element is not "this", but I don't know what is it and how to take it to change.

Comment: try changing this -> success: function (response) { NewID = response.id; }, <- with this -> success: function (response) {  drop.NewID = response.id;}

Comment: I tried, but exception in javascript says that "drop it's not define"

Comment: Well it looks like there is missing code in your question that defines the scope of "drop". Is "drop" a property of another, higher-level object?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for my iusse, hope that will help someone else. Starting for the shared code, i saved the ID that the json return into a "localStorage" variable, so my success function of AJAX will be:

```
    success: function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem("NewID", response.id);
    },
```

After this I found the function "eventRecived" triggered after the drop. Here you have the element of the dropped item, and I set here the new ID:

```
    eventReceive: function (event) {
        event.id = localStorage.getItem("NewID");
    },
```

If someone have a better solution I will be grateful. For now this solution work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For other that may encounter the problem. If you can afford another call to the server, you can just reload all your events again. I know, not ideal, but perhaps simpler.

```js
success: function (response) {
            calendar.removeAllEvents();
            calendar.refetchEvents();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've searched a bit for it and I found an easy solution. This is not pretty but it works. Given that the event that you add should be the only one without id...
I save the event in the database and I get back the id in the response of the POST. Then I add the id to the event that was dragged in the calendar in the success of the post.

Here it is :

```
    eventReceive:function(info){
      start = moment(info.event.start).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      end = moment(info.event.start).add(60,'m').format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      //console.log(start, end);

      $.ajax({
        url: SITEURL + '/testcalajax',
        data: {
          title: info.event.title,
          start: start,
          end: end,
          id: info.event.id,
          allDay :Number(info.event.allDay),
          type: 'receive'
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
          var NewEvent = calendar.getEventById( "" );
          NewEvent.setProp('id',response.id);
          
            
        }
      });
    }
```